# Pandas - Rename columns by removing text before delimiter

Tags: pandas, rename

Given below are the column names of my Dataframe

```
['user_id', 'Week 36~Sep-05 - Sep-11',
 'Week 35~Aug-29 - Sep-04', 'Week 34~Aug-22 - Aug-28']
```

I would like remove the text before the delimiter (~) if it is there in the column label and get the below column names

```
['user_id', 'Sep-05 - Sep-11', 'Aug-29 - Sep-04', 'Aug-22 - Aug-28']
```

I tried the below but it failed

```
[col.split('~')[1] for col in df.columns]
```

Error : `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: `'user_id'` doesn't contain a `~`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) here:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'.*~', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
Index(['user_id', 'Sep-05 - Sep-11', 'Aug-29 - Sep-04', 'Aug-22 - Aug-28'], dtype='object')
```

input:

```
Index(['user_id', 'Week 36~Sep-05 - Sep-11', 'Week 35~Aug-29 - Sep-04',
       'Week 34~Aug-22 - Aug-28'],
      dtype='object')
```

You approach would work with **-1** indexing:

```
df.columns = [col.split('~')[-1] for col in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are trying to split user_id using `~` and there is nothing at index `1`
Try this

```
df.columns = [col.split('~')[1] if col.startswith('Week') else col  for col in df.columns]
```